# How do lattice sites relate to an electron's momentum

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I'm trying to wrap my head around band transport of electrons in a semiconductor, and am lacking intuition as to why an electron moving from one site to another site in reciprocal space (and therefore moving between sites in real space) necessarily changes its momentum (since a change in $k$ changes its momentum expectation value via $ <p> = \hbar k$). I have seen that this expression does not give the total momentum of the electron, just the crystal momentum but I'm a little unclear of why this is.

I think in general my issue is how $k$ describes both a position in reciprocal space, but also relates to an electron's momentum, group velocity of its wavepacket, and the reciprocal of its wavelength - as these do not seem related to lattice site position.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The k-states in momentum states relate to plane waves in real space. They don't have a position, they are described as completely de-localized. If you want to talk about a electron having a well-defined position, you have to think of wave packets, i.e. superposition of plane waves. These wave packets broaden due to dispersion. This gives you a timescale up to which this wave packet discription is valid.

Comment: see this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html still classical description, that works

Comment: It is counter productive to be thinking of solving a whole lattice , considering the number of atoms in solids ( order of $10^{23}$ per mole). The band theory of solids is used, as seen here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm happy with the description of the electrons position and momentum being via a wavepacket, but am still a little confused as to why the value of k changing as the electron's wavepacket moves around the lattice means a change in the electrons momentum via <p> = hk. It seems unintuitive that a lattice site would be assigned a value of momentum?